# Error "MyVar environment variable is not set" when executing shell command using SSH.NET

Tags: c#, shell, ssh, ssh.net

I am getting an error:

> MyVar environment variable is not set

when executing shell command using SSH.NET, C#. I can execute the same command from PuTTY and everything works fine.

The code I have is

```
var client = new SshClient("myhost.mydomain", "user", "password");
client.Connect();
var cmd = "/path1/script.sh MyArgument";
var sshCommand = client.RunCommand(cmd);
var output = sshCommand.Result;
Console.WriteLine(output);
client.Disconnect();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you start a non-interactive session (using `RunCommand`), a different set of startup scripts are run and/or different paths in the scripts are taken (based on `TTY` variable).

So your environment may (most probably does) differ. Particularly the `MyVar` is not set.

---

Solutions are:

- Fix your startup scripts to set the `MyVar` even on non-interactive terminals (preferred)
- Modify SSH.NET code to issue `SendPseudoTerminalRequest` request in `.RunCommand` implementation (I didn't test this). See `Shell.Start()` for an example.